# RestClient.get force to return Response Object

Tags: ruby, rest-client

I'm using RestClient.get to get a image file, and it will return a image data string.

Sometimes the image file is not ready, it will return a 202, then RestClient.get will return a empty string. I want to know the response header, how could I force RestClient.get return a Response Object?

Comment: By reading https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client it seems you just need to examine `.code` of the return value.

Answer (score 1):

Got it, return object cheated me like this:

```
2.0.0-p451 :037 > s = RestClient.get(url)
2.0.0-p451 :035 > s.class
 => String 
2.0.0-p451 :036 > s.headers
 => {:allow=>"GET, HEAD, OPTIONS", :content_length=>"269", :content_type=>"image/png", :date=>"Wed, 23 Jul 2014 08:54:00 GMT", :last_modified=>"Wed, 23 Jul 2014 08:52:01 GMT", :server=>"nginx", :vary=>"Accept", :connection=>"keep-alive"}
```

Looks like RestClient cast some dark magic on String.

Comment: RestClient extends the returned String from the request with the `RestClient::Response` module which includes `AbstractResponse`. So the headersmethod  is for example defined in `AbstractResponse`.

Documentation on the Response module including methods included from AbstractResponse can be found here: http://rubydoc.info/github/rest-client/rest-client/RestClient/Response

The extending of the string can be found here: https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client/blob/26b5ff3ba235ce05eacd1057fc1d319d7106e37d/lib/restclient/abstract_response.rb